# OCaml error: wrong type of expression in constructor

Tags: ocaml

I have a function `save` that take standard input, which is used individually like this:

```
./try < input.txt (* save function is in try file *)
```

input.txt

```
2
3
10 29 23
22 14 9
```

and now i put the function into another file called `path.ml` which is a part of my interpreter. Now I have a problem in defining the type of Save function and this is because save function has type in_channel, but when i write

```
type term = Save of in_channel
```

ocamlc complain about the parameter in the `command` function.

How can i fix this error? This is the reason why in my last question posted on stackoverflow, I asked for the way to express a variable that accept any type. I understand the answers but actually it doesn't help much in make the code running.

This is my code:

```
(* Data types *)

open Printf
type term = Print_line_in_file of int*string
        | Print of string       
        | Save of in_channel  (* error here *)  
;;


let input_line_opt ic =
  try Some (input_line ic)
  with End_of_file -> None

let nth_line n filename =
  let ic = open_in filename in
  let rec aux i =
    match input_line_opt ic with
      | Some line ->
          if i = n then begin
            close_in ic;
            (line)
          end else aux (succ i)
      | None ->
          close_in ic;
          failwith "end of file reached"
  in
    aux 1

(* get all lines *)
let k = ref 1
let first = ref ""
let second = ref ""
let sequence = ref []
let append_item lst a = lst @ [a]

let save () = 
    try
        while true do
            let line = input_line stdin in
                if k = ref 1
                    then
                    begin
                        first := line;
                        incr k;
                    end else 
                if k = ref 2
                    then
                    begin
                        second := line;
                        incr k;
                    end else                
                    begin
                        sequence := append_item !sequence line;
                        incr k;
                    end
            done;
        None
    with
End_of_file -> None;;



let rec command term = match term with
    | Print (n) -> print_endline n
    | Print_line_in_file (n, f) -> print_endline (nth_line n f)
    | Save () -> save ()
;;
```

**EDIT**

Error in code:

Save of in_channel:

```
Error: This pattern matches values of type unit
       but a pattern was expected which matches values of type in_channel
```

Save of unit:

```
Error: This expression has type 'a option
       but an expression was expected of type unit
```

Comment: Please edit your post with the precise error message.

Comment: If you compile this in the normal way with ocamlc then it will tell you the line and column where the error was found, that makes debugging a lot easier. (If you're doing that already, please just include that info in the question.)

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do with this `Save`. Can you explain it ?

Comment: Because this path.ml file is a part of my interpreter. The keyword is defined in lexer, token for the keyword is defined in parser and now I want the save keyword can do an action, which is read stdin. So the save file do this task, but under another keyword defined in my lexer.

Comment: if you try copy the part from the comment (* get all line *) to the line before `let rec .. ` and save to new file. try command `ocamlc -o <name>.ml`. with input is in my edit you will understand

Answer (score 0):

There are many errors in this code, so it's hard to know where to start.

One problem is this: your `save` function has type `unit -> 'a option`. So it's not the same type as the other branches of your final `match`. The fix is straightforward: `save` should return `()`, not `None`. In OCaml these are completely different things.

The immediate problem seems to be that you have `Save ()` in your match, but have declared `Save` as taking an input channel. Your current code doesn't have any way to pass the input channel to the `save` function, but if it did, you would want something more like this in your match:

```
| Save ch -> save ch
```

Errors like this suggest (to me) that you're not so familiar with OCaml's type system. It would probably save you a lot of trouble if you went through a tutorial of some kind before writing much more code. You can find tutorials at http://ocaml.org.